# How to access a Process running on docker on a host from a remote host

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

How to access or connect to a process running on docker on host A from a remote host B

consider a Host A with ip 192.168.0.3 which is running a application on docker on port 3999 .
If i want to access that application from  remote machine with IP 192.168.0.4  in same subnet.

To be precise i am running Kafka producer on the server and i am trying to receive using Kafka-console-Consumer.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `--net=host` to `run` your container and it'll use the host's network stack, then you can connect to the application running inside container like it's running on host directly.
- Port mapping, use option `-p` to map the port inside your container to a port of your host. e.g. `docker run -d -p <container port>:<host port> <image>`, then you can connect to `<host>:<host port>` to connect your application inside container
- Docker's [built-in multi-host network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/). In early releases the network driver is isolated from docker's core, you have to use 3rd party tools like [flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) or [weave](https://www.weave.works/documentation/net-latest-plugin/) for multi-host connection, but [from release 1.9, it has been merged into docker](https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/docker-multi-host-networking-ga/). You can follow it's guide to set it up.

Hope this is helpful :-)

Comment: @NaveenHolla Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to bind docker container's port to the Host A:

> docker run -d -p 3999:3999 kafka-producer

Then you need to access Host A from Host B using IP:Port

```
192.168.0.3:3999
```